# CSS submenu hover color issue

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

I have a submenu in WordPress that was set up as a list in the following way:

```
.sidebar .widget { margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left:20px;}
.sidebar .widget h5 {line-height: 13px; margin-bottom: 30px; font-weight: bold;font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif; }
.sidebar .widget ul li { margin-bottom: 2px;background-color:#b3b1b2;padding:6px 2px;  }
.sidebar .widget ul li a { margin-bottom: 2px;background-color:#b3b1b2;color:#ffffff ;padding:6px 2px; }
.sidebar .widget ul li a:hover { margin-bottom: 2px;background-color:#dadada;color:#202e3b ;padding:6px 2px; }
.sidebar .widget ul li a:active { margin-bottom: 2px;background-color:#dadada;color:#202e3b ;padding:6px 2px; }
```

See the page here: http://www.mahabbanetwork.com/who-we-are/

However, I would like the hover state to change the colour of the whole "bar" to the lighter grey, i.e. the full width instead of just the text-background which it is at present. I have played around with increasing the righthand padding but it, of course, increases it relative to the length/number of characters of the text link, which is different for each link.

This site uses a pre-coded WP template so I am not sure how to amend it to achieve the desire effect without messing things up elsewhere on the site.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:hover` to `li`

```
.sidebar .widget ul li:hover 
{ 
  background-color:#dadada;
  color:#202e3b ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the hover state grey color to `.sidebar .widget ul li:hover` instead of `.sidebar .widget ul li a:hover`

```
.sidebar .widget ul li:hover 
{ 
  background-color:#dadada;
  color:#202e3b ;
}
```